# SAS - How to share an enterprise miner project

Tags: sas

Users can't see projects they didn't create in Enterprise Miner. We have opened up file permissions on the Unix server for all of the projects, but they don't show up in the 'open project' dialog. What are we doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Users can access projects that are on the workspace server but not registered in metadata for them. To do so, they need to open up permissions on the project folders. Then follow the instructions for "Defining Migrated Projects in SAS Enterprise Miner".

Info is here: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/emag/65360/PDF/default/emag.pdf
Page 67

This is in the context of SAS EM 12.1

Answer (score 1):

In addition to setting the UNIX server directory permissions, you probably need to change the umask on the `workspace server` being executed by Enterprise Miner.  See [this SAS Usage note](http://support.sas.com/kb/30/756.html).